# Close the window when Command+W is pressed

Tags: flutter

I don't see that being implemented in the default app template on macOS. When I pressed Command+W, it does nothing. How can we do that in flutter?

Comment: For closing windows in macOS you have to press cmd+q

Comment: @rahulVFlutterAndroid most macOS apps also support cmd+w to close the window

Comment: yes some clone macOS does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: For exiting a window on mac, you need to press command+Q, this approach is if you want to specifically detect command+W.*

To exit a Flutter app (not for IOS), you can call:

```
 SystemNavigator.pop();
```

which, if you take a look internally at its code, calls:

```
SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop'
```

So, to detect Command+W you can setup a keyboard listener:

```dart
 RawKeyboard.instance.addListener((key) {
      if (key.isMetaPressed && key.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.keyW)) {
        SystemNavigator.pop();
      }
    });
```

Complete code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    RawKeyboard.instance.addListener((key) {
      if (key.isMetaPressed && key.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.keyW)) {
        SystemNavigator.pop();
      }
    });

    return Scaffold(
      body: Text("Press on the command+w key to close the app"),
    );
  }
}
```